# car Package in R Errors

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the package `car` in R via the command line.

```
install.packages("car")

        Error : package ‘Matrix’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
       ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
       * removing ‘/afs/umbc.edu/users/w/j/wjohn1/home/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-    library/3.3/RcppEigen’
        * installing *source* package ‘MatrixModels’ ...
    ** package ‘MatrixModels’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** R
    ** preparing package for lazy loading
    Error : package ‘Matrix’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
    ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘MatrixModels’
     ERROR: dependency ‘RcppEigen’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
     ERROR: dependency ‘MatrixModels’ is not available for package ‘quantreg’
   ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘pbkrtest’
   ERROR: dependencies ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’ are not available for package ‘car’

 The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmpois2Ys/downloaded_packages’
      Warning messages:
     1: In install.packages("car") :
            installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
     2: In install.packages("car") :
             installation of package ‘MatrixModels’ had non-zero exit status
     3: In install.packages("car") :
             installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
     4: In install.packages("car") :
             installation of package ‘quantreg’ had non-zero exit status
     5: In install.packages("car") :
              installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
      6: In install.packages("car") :
             installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried to install the above `lme`, `matrix`,etc and I still return more errors such as the below for `lme`:

```
Warning messages:
     1: In install.packages("lme4") :
         installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
     2: In install.packages("lme4") :
         installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: can you post re results of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: > sessioninfo()
Error: could not find function "sessioninfo"

Comment: if you cant find ``sessionInfo()`` then it means theres something with your installation of R (or at least its base packages). Both ``car`` and ``utils`` (which ``sessionInfo`` is a part of) are part of Base R...perhaps try uninstalling R and reinstalling it.

Comment: Note the capitalization of i in `sessionInfo()`. Also try with `install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE)`. If all fails, download the zip/tar.gz file and do `install.packages("path/to/zip/file",repos=NULL,type="source")`. It is best to check out the [web page of package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html]) before installation and see "depends on"

Comment: You can also try update.packages(). Indeed if you only install few packages yourself it might be easiest to remove the directory where they are installed, create a new one and install them again.